# Were the Terminators in the later movie faster and more powerful. or merely shown this way due to improvements in SFX?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series

As the Terminator movies go on, the Terminators appear to be stronger and to move faster. This includes the models played by Schwarzenegger, two of which were supposed to be the exact same character portrayed in different timelines.

Did they actually become stronger and more powerful in canon, or was this purely because SFX had improved and the film makers were able to portray them as faster and more destructive?

Comment: IMO there are stronger because of technology. The first Terminator of all (before 800 model) was just a "*better killer robot*". As time goes by, they evolve.

Comment: Which two Terminators do you think are the same from different timelines? The young Terminator in *Genisys* and the Terminator from *The Terminator*?

Comment: I don't, I'm just curious if I missed a connection that they put in

Comment: It is very clear in Terminator 2 that there is a new, improved liquid-metal terminator with radically different technology. This was possible to depict because special effects tech improved but also makes sense in the story. Later movies make further tech leaps.

Comment: I'm not buying the premise. Is the T-800 from T2 stronger and faster than the bad one from the first film? Maybe the elderly one from Dark Fate beats them all?

Comment: @Greendrake, the premise is that the Terminator played by Schwarzenegger in Dark Fate moved faster and was more destructive to the environment than the Terminator in the original movie. This is objectively true based on the visuals of the movie. The question is whether this is purely down to improvements in how films are made in reality, or in how Terminators are made in universe.

Comment: @AaarghZombies I didn't notice it being objectively true. Can you give some examples where the Dark Fate T-800 is faster/more destructive?

Comment: In the original he is shown breaking drywall panels and wooden doors which is a simple practical effect, in df he punches out concrete and metal beans which requires cgi. The movement rate in the original is also in real time as it is done by the actor, in df he moves faster than the actor could move in real life as it is cgi.

Comment: It's due to real world advancements in computers. No one would've had this Q in 1984. In *Westworld* 1973, he walks into a warm room and can't see anything. In *The Terminator*, we're shown their thought process where it takes a few seconds to decide to tell a guy to piss off or not. GPT can do that in 2ms. - *slow is scary* : a concept Patrick took to the bank after studying how felines hunt. - Also, there's the part after a brisk jog to keep up, that he jumps on top the car like a madman and is one handful of clothing away from ending the movie. Risk assessment: that move cost him his hair.

Answer (score 2):

With the exception of Terminator 3 (in which Schwarzenegger plays an updated T850 model), the Terminators are canonically the same type of machine. Any differences in strength or agility are therefore purely due to the SFX being upgraded.

However, it's important to remember that the 'good' Terminators in the sequels have all been reprogrammed. In the Director's cut of T2, we see that this involves turning on a hidden 'learning' function on the Terminator's central processing unit.

It is therefore reasonable, in-universe, to attribute any improvements in strategy or cunning to this reprogramming.

In other words, the machines get smarter in the sequels, even though the bodies are the same.